# How to speed up Rails 5 "system" tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Coming from rspec, we can run our feature specs with Capybara pretty fast as long as we don't enable JavaScript. How can we speed up the start and/or execution time of the built-in Rails 5 system tests?

My current *application_system_test_case.rb*:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :poltergeist
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now I remember. Capybara uses the RackTest driver by default, which is pretty darn fast. You can do the same with the Rails system test configuration.

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :rack_test
end
```

One drawback I'm not certain of yet is how you might switch drivers for some tests that *do* require JavaScript execution and therefore need a true headless browser to drive the system tests. (In rspec, we'd pass the `js: true` option in the feature test definition.)

Comment: An addition on how to switch the driver if JS is needed with default minitest would be awesome!